# How to make an Squid-Cache internal URL rewrite?

Tags: http, mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting, squid

url_rewrite_program by squid-cache really redirects the URL. In other words, the end-user gets a response back that says "redirectted page from foo to bar", and then the user makes another request to the redirected address. I don't want this.

what I want to achieve is similar to apache's mod_rewrite. I want an abselutely transparent rewriting mechanism. So that the user requests for a spefific content, and he gets it as a response (regardless of his initial requested URL) without any HTTP redirection.

the reason I want to avoid redirection via http is because I don't want the end-user to see internal application structures. For example, he requests "application1.foo.com", and he gets content of a URL that's much lengthier. So if the end-user bookmarks it, he bookmarks my clean little URL (application1.foo.com", this is good to keep users away from such details, it eventually gives them a uniform URL for the service even if I change it in the future. For example, I might map application1.foo.com to badprovider.com/path/to/file.php initially, and then change it to goodprovider.com/file.php and the user won't notice that. The advantage is, for example, end-user bookmarks would remain correct, as well as regulating their behaviour in a more guided manner.

Comment: It is better to implement this using web server's functionality (Apache's mod_rewrite, IIS URL Rewrite module etc)

Comment: and how would it fit into that? the reason I'm using squid-cache is that it is already authenticating users, and I want to apply the rewrite thing on per user basis. So not all users' URLs will get rewritten.

Comment: This sort of "small details" should be in your question from the beginning highlighted somehow and not as a small side note.

Comment: u r kinda stepping on my nerves :D.. i've already looked into it, and squid-cache is the easier way as it already authenticates stuff... doing it with mod_rewrite means essentially using mod_proxy too and ignore squid-cache. this is not feasible.. it's a limitation in squid-cache i guess.. this is sado.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try setting squid as a reverse proxy with the 'accel' mode ? It worked for me:

```
acl all src all

http_port 3128 accel vhost
cache_peer 127.0.0.1 parent 80 0 no-query originserver name=myAccel
acl our_sites dstdomain your_domain.net
http_access allow our_sites
http_access deny all
cache_peer_access myAccel allow our_sites
cache_peer_access myAccel deny all
negative_ttl 0

access_log /var/log/squid/access.log squid
hosts_file /etc/hosts
coredump_dir /var/spool/squid
```

your_domain.net is the domain you want to redirect